# Passing Variables to Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will search my Active Directory for users with passwords that will expire in 14 days and email the user a reminder message. For the most part I have the script working as intended, but I am not getting the proper output for the emails.

This is the script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$below = (Get-Date).AddDays(-77)
$above = (Get-Date).AddDays(-76)
$Persons = Get-ADUser -Filter {PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -AND (PasswordLastSet -lt $above -AND PasswordLastSet -gt $below) -AND (LastLogonDate -like "*") -AND (MAil -like "*")}

foreach ($Person IN $Persons) {
$body = "Your Windows password will expire in 14 days. Please consider changing your password. - $User.Name - $User.PasswordLastSet"
Send-MailMessage -To $User.Mail -Subject "Alert! Password Expiring Soon!" -From 'Do_Not_Reply@domain.com' -Body $body -SmtpServer smtp.server.com
}
```

This is what I am getting in the body of the mails it sends.

> Your Windows password will expire in 14 days. Please consider changing your password. - .Name - .PasswordLastSet

How do I pass the users name and password last set data to the body text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [subexpressions `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to access the properties on `$User` in the string:

```
"... - $($User.Name) - $($User.PasswordLastSet)"
```

Otherwise, PowerShell will only parse `$User` as a variable and the `.Name` and `.PasswordLastSet` parts will be treated as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to iCodez's (correct) answer is to use the [format operator (`-f`)](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html):

```
$body = "...your password. - {0} - {1}" -f $User.Name,$User.PasswordLastSet
```